# file upload inside a BeginForm

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to add file upload function inside BeginForm once I click file upload submit button I want to direct to another method to upload that file , not the same BeginForm action.

how can I do this using Ajax Function

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Field_Values", "Home", new { Product_ID = ViewBag.Product_ID , FieldID = ViewBag.FieldID }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                        if (condition)
                        {     
                                <input type="file" name="files">   
                                <input id="adddetails" type="button" value="Upload File to Server">
                        } 



            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save Details" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>

}

<script>
 $().ready(function () {

        $("#adddetails").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/FileUpload/Financing_Product_Feature_Upload",
                data: 
                {
                       ....
                },
                success: function (data) {

                }

            });
        });
</script>
```

then I  have controller method as follows in FileUpload controller Class

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Financing_Product_Feature_Upload(HttpPostedFileBase files, string productid)
    {
```

My question is to define above `ajax` call that can upload file

please advise

Answer (score 0):

Well You can do it, but unfortunately in my opinion You will not be able to pass parameters to controller action, like `productId` , but what can You do, You can just have a hidden field for that value.

Your ajax form should look like this:

```
$("#adddetails").click(function (evt) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/FileUpload/Financing_Product_Feature_Upload",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: new FormData($('.myForm').get(0)),
        success: function (message) {
            alert(message);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("There was error uploading files!");
        }
    });
});
```

The file input should like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Field_Values", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "myForm"})){
<input type="file" name="files" />
@Html.Hidden("ProductId", ViewBag.Product_ID);
}
```

And the controller should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Financing_Product_Feature_Upload()
{
var files = Request.Files;
var productId = Request.Params["ProductId"].ToString();
}
```

I hope that might be useful for You and You get the main concept of my answer, good luck ;)

Comment: if  I have several properties other than file attachment , how to get that inside ajax  `data: new FormData($('.myForm').get(0)),` ?

Comment: Well, actually now when `processData: false,` , so you cannot pass any properties to controller only model, files or some other data, my suggestion is to use hidden fields. Unfortunately, I do not know any other solution how to retrieve files or pass properties with ajax at controller action.

Comment: Actually  I meant If I have  several properties other than file attachment, then how to get exact ID , what do you meant by `$('.myForm').get(0)` ?, is that means first one of the properties ?

Comment: Ohhh, it just get's the form, i guess it works also like this `new FormData($('.myForm')),` or this `new FormData($('.myForm').serialize()),` so it does not matter if you pass more than 1 parameter and so on, still it will get all the files you need.